# Does the system allocates memory from high->low or the reverse?

Tags: stack, cpu-architecture

IIRC it should be `high->low`,but according to this image,it's `low->high`.

[image]

I'm now confused,which is the case?

Seems the code is also executed from `low->hight`:

```
0x0000000000400498 <main+0>:    push   %rbp
0x0000000000400499 <main+1>:    mov    %rsp,%rbp
0x000000000040049c <main+4>:    sub    $0x10,%rsp
0x00000000004004a0 <main+8>:    movl   $0x6,-0x4(%rbp)
```

Comment: It really depends on what "system" you are talking about - you need to be a *lot* more specific, e.g. architecture, OS, ABI and also what context you're talking about, such as stack allocations, heap allocations, linker static/global allocations, etc. From the diagram I'm guessing you're talking about stack allocations on x86 ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How will you find out if a stack grows up or down in a system ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361123/how-will-you-find-out-if-a-stack-grows-up-or-down-in-a-system)

Answer (score 2):

On Intel x86/x64, which are the most popular architectures that run Windows, the stack "grows" towards the lower addresses. I.e., pushing onto the stack involves subtracting from the stack pointer (ESP), and popping from the stack involves adding to the stack pointer.

The stack grows from the top to the bottom in your example. This is the function's prologue, and it uses the SUB instruction to allocate stack space for local variables. You might be confusing the stack with the memory in which your *program* is stored -- in that area, the CPU executes instructions sequentially, from low to high addresses, until a branch (e.g. JMP) instruction is encountered.